# Question about storing/retrieving data for a complex page

Tags: php, mysql, json

1. My stack is php and mysql.
2. I am trying to design a page to display details of a mutual fund.
3. Data for a single fund is distributed over 15-20 different tables.
4. Currently, my front-end is a brute-force php page that queries/joins these tables using 8 different queries for a single scheme. It's messy and poor performing.

I am considering alternatives. Good thing is that the data changes only once a day, so I can do some preprocessing.

An option that I am considering is to create run these queries for every fund (about 2000 funds)  and create a complex json object for each of them, store it in mysql indexed for the fund code, retrieve the json at run time and show the data. I am thinking of using the simple json_object() mysql function to create the json, and json_decode in php to get the values for display. Is this a good approach?

I was tempted to store them in a separate MongoDB store - would that be an overkill for this?

Any other suggestion?

Thanks much!

Comment: have you considered using a cache solution such as memcached?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the funds are randomly picked by users and the same fund getting picked multiple times in a day are low. So, cache hit ratios would likely not be high.

Comment: How "poor" is the performance? There's "I know this could be faster" and then there's "people will stop using my site because it is so slow". Where are you on this spectrum?

Comment: The latter, unfortunately. And my SEO is suffering also, I think, because of the poor performance. A full page load takes 5-6 seconds to complete. Here's an example: https://primeinvestor.in/mutual-funds/fund/Aditya-Birla-SL-Frontline-Equity-Fund(G)-Direct-Plan/18249

Comment: It's pretty hard to suggest something with literally no information about the architecture. How are the tables organized? Do you have proper indexes etc?

Comment: Nothing on that page appears overly complex at first glance, but we obviously don't know your structure. You should just start debugging to find what is the slowest part, such as possibly just a single query. You might be able to throw an index at the database and fix everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To meet your objective of quick pageviews, your overnight-run approach is very good.  You could generate JSON objects with your distilled data, or even prerendered HTML pages, and store them.

You can certainly store JSON objects in MySQL columns. If you don't need the database server to search the objects, simply use `TEXT` (or `LONGTEXT`) data types to store them.

To my way of thinking, adding a new type of server (mongodb) to your operations to store a few thousand JSON objects does not seem worth the the trouble. If you find it necessary to search the contents of your JSON objects, another type of server might be useful, however.

Other things to consider:

1. Optimize your SQL queries. Read up: https://use-the-index-luke.com and other sources of good info. Consider your queries one-by-one starting with the slowest one. Use the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) or even the [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) command to get your MySQL server to tell you how it plans each query. And judiciously add indexes. Using the [query-optimization](/questions/tagged/query-optimization) tag here on StackOverflow, you can get help. Many queries can be optimized by adding indexes to MySQL without changing anything in your php code or your data. So this can be an ongoing project rather than a big new software release.
2. Consider measuring your query times. You can do this with [MySQL's slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html). The point of this is to identify your "dirty dozen" slowest queries in a particular time period. Then, see step one.
3. Make your pages fill up progressively, to keep your users busy reading while you get the data they need. Put the toplevel stuff (fund name, etc) in server-side HTML so search engines can see it. Use some sort of front-end tech (React, maybe, or [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) that [fetch data via AJAX](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)) to render your pages client-side, and provide REST endpoints on your server to get the data, in JSON format, for each data block in the page.
4. In your overnight run create a [sitemap file](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/overview) along with your JSON data rows. That lets you control exactly how you want search engines to present your data.

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed and very helpful reply. Gives me the confidence to go ahead (the point on sitemap is really, really useful). I have checked on indexes, measured query times etc. Nothing too out of ordinary there, hence my seeking a 'preprocessing' solution. Thanks again!